# How to extend rows and columns to fit the text when using printDocument

Tags: c#, datagridview, printdocument

I was trying to print a datagridview but it seems there is wrong with my code

Variables

```
 StringFormat strFormat; 
 ArrayList arrColumnLefts = new ArrayList();
 ArrayList arrColumnWidths = new ArrayList();
 int iCellHeight = 0;
 int iTotalWidth = 0; 
 int iRow = 0;
 bool bFirstPage = false; 
 bool bNewPage = false;
 int iHeaderHeight = 0;
```

This is my `printDocument2_Beginprint`

```
 try
        {
            strFormat = new StringFormat();
            strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            strFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;

            arrColumnLefts.Clear();
            arrColumnWidths.Clear();
            iCellHeight = 0;
            iRow = 0;
            bFirstPage = true;
            bNewPage = true;


            // Calculating Total Widths
            iTotalWidth = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvGridCol in advancedDataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                iTotalWidth += dgvGridCol.Width;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

printDocument2_printPage
     private void printDocument2_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Set the left margin
                int iLeftMargin = e.MarginBounds.Left;
                //Set the top margin
                int iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
                //Whether more pages have to print or not
                bool bMorePagesToPrint = false;
                int iTmpWidth = 0;

            //For the first page to print set the cell width and header height
            if (bFirstPage)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in advancedDataGridView1.Columns)
                {
                    iTmpWidth = (int)(Math.Floor((double)((double)GridCol.Width /
                                   (double)iTotalWidth * (double)iTotalWidth *
                                   ((double)e.MarginBounds.Width / (double)iTotalWidth))));

                    iHeaderHeight = (int)(e.Graphics.MeasureString(GridCol.HeaderText,
                                GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font, iTmpWidth).Height) + 11;

                    // Save width and height of headres
                    arrColumnLefts.Add(iLeftMargin);
                    arrColumnWidths.Add(iTmpWidth);
                    iLeftMargin += iTmpWidth;
                }
            }
            //Loop till all the grid rows not get printed
            while (iRow <= advancedDataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                DataGridViewRow GridRow = advancedDataGridView1.Rows[iRow];
                //Set the cell height
                iCellHeight = GridRow.Height + 5;
                int iCount = 0;
                //Check whether the current page settings allo more rows to print
                if (iTopMargin + iCellHeight >= e.MarginBounds.Height + e.MarginBounds.Top)
                {
                    bNewPage = true;
                    bFirstPage = false;
                    bMorePagesToPrint = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (bNewPage)
                    {
                        //Draw Header
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("Customer Summary", new Font(advancedDataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                                Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top -
                                e.Graphics.MeasureString("Customer Summary", new Font(advancedDataGridView1.Font,
                                FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                        String strDate = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                        //Draw Date
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(strDate, new Font(advancedDataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
                                Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width -
                                e.Graphics.MeasureString(strDate, new Font(advancedDataGridView1.Font,
                                FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Width), e.MarginBounds.Top -
                                e.Graphics.MeasureString("Customer Summary", new Font(new Font(advancedDataGridView1.Font,
                                FontStyle.Bold), FontStyle.Bold), e.MarginBounds.Width).Height - 13);

                        //Draw Columns                 
                        iTopMargin = e.MarginBounds.Top;
                        foreach (DataGridViewColumn GridCol in advancedDataGridView1.Columns)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray),
                                new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                                new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight));

                            e.Graphics.DrawString(GridCol.HeaderText, GridCol.InheritedStyle.Font,
                                new SolidBrush(GridCol.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], iTopMargin,
                                (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iHeaderHeight), strFormat);
                            iCount++;
                        }
                        bNewPage = false;
                        iTopMargin += iHeaderHeight;
                    }
                    iCount = 0;
                    //Draw Columns Contents                
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell Cel in GridRow.Cells)
                    {
                        if (Cel.Value != null)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.DrawString(Cel.Value.ToString(), Cel.InheritedStyle.Font,
                                        new SolidBrush(Cel.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                                        new RectangleF((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount], (float)iTopMargin,
                                        (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], (float)iCellHeight), strFormat);
                        }
                        //Drawing Cells Borders 
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle((int)arrColumnLefts[iCount],
                                iTopMargin, (int)arrColumnWidths[iCount], iCellHeight));

                        iCount++;
                    }
                }
                iRow++;
                iTopMargin += iCellHeight;
            }

            //If more lines exist, print another page.
            if (bMorePagesToPrint)
                e.HasMorePages = true;
            else
                e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }
}
```

So this is the output, all columns and rows are to small to show the details, if someone can help that would be great you can try to copy my code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that the code is working as desired. Based on the attached picture: So the table is filling the page from margin to margin, but there's too much information, right? You have few choices I can think of, three are obvious, but may be unwanted: You can ommit some columns to allow more space for the rest, or use landscape mode instead of portrait, or choose a larger page, like A3 instead of A4.

The only practical that comes to my mind: Use more lines per each record (`DataGridView` `Row`). You can have some cells (usually the ID) spanning over more rows and then to have the conent nicely arranged into multi-row arragement.

[image: Multirows]

As for the way you do it, it seems to me pretty complicated (but nice piece of coding). You're making a picture using basic GDI functions and then send it to printer, it seems to me. I'm personally using [PDFsharp & MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/), which produces a true printable document (PDF) with way less hassle, I'd say. The reason I recommend it in this case is, that it allows easy rowspan (and colspan), that is to merge table cells.

Comment: If I will use that library is there a way that i can put a title int the firstpage only together with subtitle?

Comment: You can do whatever you wish, even very complex documents. Just decide right from beginning whether to use PDFSharp (it's more like drawing pages, i.e. no object flow, no automatic page ends) or MigraDoc (more "document" approach, usually more convenient). There are a lot of examples, here are the First Steps: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocFirstSteps.ashx